# cart checkout price add to payfast

Tags: c#

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //var clinicbusiness = new ClinicBusiness       ();

        return View();
    }

     [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult ValidateCommand()
    {
        var pa = new PaymentView();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)

            return View("ValidateCommand");
        else
            return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectFromPaypal()
    {
        return View("RedirectFromPaypal");
    }

    private ActionResult View(Func<ActionResult> RedirectFromPaypal)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

this is my controller and i have a problem taking items from A CART 
how to add cart items to a controller n accumulate price
using payfast checkout button

Comment: What is a "cart"? One of your models? If so, you should post the relevant code.

Comment: There are just too many parts missing from your question and code. Please specify what you need help with and what parts you have to play with.